# return a string value from an EventHandler void

Tags: c#, .net, void, eventhandler, autodesk

I'm using an EventHandler to check which button was clicked inside Autocad, the only problem is I don't know how can I return the string value from the void and use it inside the main class. It would be great to get some Help!

```
Autodesk.Windows.ComponentManager.ItemExecuted += new EventHandler<Autodesk.Internal.Windows.RibbonItemExecutedEventArgs>(ItemExecutedTest);
void ItemExecutedTest(object sender, Autodesk.Internal.Windows.RibbonItemExecutedEventArgs e)
{
string scriptName = e.Item.Text;
}

string script = scriptName;
```

Comment: This question is a little vague (well at least for me), Whos event is that? did you write it, who is raising the even? does it contain a string property you can use

Comment: save that value to static field and get it on where you wish to use.

Comment: @Arphile it doesn't need to be static, though.

Comment: @Fildor but there's no out method right? if EventArgs doesn't contains String return field, static is the best method to solve this problem.

Comment: @Arphile Why? All you need is a private property or field in the class where the Handler is defined. I don't see why static should be necessary or be beneficial, here.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously cannot change the return type of your EventHandler and doing so wouldn't help neither. What you need to do is: set a class field or property.

Example:

```
public class Example
{

    private string ScriptName {get; set;} = string.Empty;

    public Example()
    {
         // register events
         Autodesk.Windows.ComponentManager.ItemExecuted += new EventHandler<Autodesk.Internal.Windows.RibbonItemExecutedEventArgs>(ItemExecutedTest);
    }

    void ItemExecutedTest(object sender, Autodesk.Internal.Windows.RibbonItemExecutedEventArgs e)
    {
         ScriptName = e.Item.Text;
         // class property now contains e.Item.Text
    }
}
```

Heads Up: If you access UI-Items inside that handler, you need to check if you are*) on the UI Thread and possibly marshal to it.

*) "you are" as in "if the handler is executed on the UI Thread" ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only normal way of passing a value to the event caller from the event handler is through the event args. You should also add a flag e.g. IsHandled that you can set to true.
The dirty way is by making the handler non void.

Comment: Why do you think OP wants to return a value to the event source that the event source already knows? _"...and use it **inside the main class** "_ (emphasis by me) I conclude that the string shall be known in the class that _handles_ the event.

Comment: I don’t know... Some people have weird problems.

Comment: _"The dirty way is by making the handler non void."_ You cannot do that. This is apparently some plugin to a CAD software and that handler most probably one if its interfaces, so you're stuck with `public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);`

Comment: Well the question is “ return a string value from an EventHandler void”... I am just giving him the possibilities. Apparently the question that the OP asked has nothing to do with the provided scenario. The answer to that is “you cannot”. You can only pass it back as a static public field/property or have a singleton class somewhere to store the data. Both solutions are fragile.